# Delete Subscription is not working in Youtube API V3

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to perform delete subscription of youtube api V3 in my application. But I am not able to get it. Here my code is

```
HttpDelete httDelete = new HttpDelete("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions");
httDelete.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httDelete.setHeader("Authorization",MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
httDelete.setHeader("id",channelId");
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httDelete);
String responseString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

Here is my response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
  {
   "domain": "global",
  "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: id",
  "locationType": "parameter",
  "location": "id"
 }
   ],
  "code": 400,
"message": "Required parameter: id"
  }
```

Please give me any suggestions.I am waiting for your quick response.

Comment: Is your code correct? why there is a double quote in `setHeader("id", channelId")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the "id" in the body of the request, not on the header. 
as in

> DELETE
>   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?id=id&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

but I suggest you to use [YouTube API Java client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) for easy of use.

There is an Android working example on [YouTube Direct Lite for Android](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android) project.